# How to evade writing a lot of repetitive code when mapping?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, automapper, architectural-patterns

I have a data access layer (DAL) using Entity Framework, and I want to use Automapper to communicate with upper layers.  I will have to map data transfer objects (DTOs) to entities as the first operation on every method, process my inputs, then proceed to map from entities to DTOs. What would you do to skip writing this code?

As an example, see this:

```
//This is a common method in my DAL
public CarDTO getCarByOwnerAndCreditStatus(OwnerDTO ownerDto, CreditDto creditDto)
{
    //I want to automatize this code on all methods similar to this
    Mapper.CreateMap<OwnerDTO,Owner>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<CreditDTO,Credit>();
    Owner owner = Mapper.map(ownerDto);
    Owner credit = Mapper.map(creditDto)

    //... Some code processing the mapped DTOs

   //I want to automatize this code on all methods similar to this 

   Mapper.CreateMap<Car,CarDTO>();
   Car car = Mapper.map(ownedCar);
   return car;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the repetitive code you are trying to avoid writing, and the objects that it is sandwiched between?

Comment: is there any difference between you dtos and entities ?

Comment: Yes. Entities are EntityObjects and DTOs are POCOs. They have the same parameters, but POCOs have POCO collections resembling the collections that can be foun of entities.

Comment: Don't write repetitive code, that's how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use code generation to generate the repetitive code.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because you did not explain how would you solve the problem. To say that a code generator solves the problem because it generates repetitive code automatically is to say the obvious... (excuse me if I'm mean)

Comment: @JPCF: No excuse required. I'm usually the one being called mean ;-)

Comment: @JPCF: Also, I don't know what you have to start from. If you have a good model from which to generate code, then use a [T4 Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). If not, then you'll need some other technology, or else, create a good model.

Comment: The problem here is that every method has different signatures, meaning that it could be impossible to write code in a generalized way... I was thinking about using a reflection mechanism like "read the input, look into it, and then use automapper..." but it seems to be too difficult....

Comment: @JPCF: first, refactor that code to put the "repetitive" code in only one or two locations (possibly methods). Then see about code generation. In particular, I see from your other question that you're using EF4. You have the option to generate arbitrary code from your EF conceptual model.

Comment: @JPCF: See [Customizing Entity Classes using T4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx) and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=entity+framework+t4 in general.